# Error while accessing json type data, in postgreSQL 9.6

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I've created a table 'orders' containing `JSON` data in PostgreSQL 9.6 server using as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
   ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   info json NOT NULL
);
```

Inserted the data:

```
INSERT INTO orders (info)
VALUES
   (
      '{ "customer": "Lily Bush", "items": {"product": "Diaper","qty": 24}}'
   ),
   (
      '{ "customer": "Josh William", "items": {"product": "Toy Car","qty": 1}}'
   ),
   (
      '{ "customer": "Mary Clark", "items": {"product": "Toy Train","qty": 2}}'
   );
```

Later I'm trying to access the data using the following select query :

```
SELECT
   info ->> 'customer' AS customer
FROM
   orders;
```

I expect this to be my output:

```
Lily Bush
Josh William
Mary Clark
```

But I'm getting this :

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ->> unknown LINE 2:    info ->>
>   'customer' AS customer
>                   ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. SQL
>   state: 42883 Character: 16

Can someone suggest, what should I do regarding this?

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f9a45616397a24f62e6b1fb9eee6195d

Comment: I tried again, it didn't work.

Comment: Then you are doing something differently than you are showing us. I copied your script to the dbfiddle site and it ran without problems (see the link in my first comment)

Comment: Yeah I saw. I copied the queries that you've run there. I got the same error as before.

Comment: @JimJones 'customer' not being explicitly recognized as text isn't the problem.  It should still resolve the '->>' operator based on the type of the left operand, and therefore infer that 'customer' must be of type text.

Comment: You are probably not actually using 9.6.  What does `select version()` show?

Comment: @jjanes I thought it might be the error because the type of the parameter is `json ->> unknown` and I recall having issues when json functions do not have the proper parameter types :-D have a nice weekend

Comment: @jjanes, yeah you're right it was problem with the version. So sorry for a useless doubt. I don't know how 9.2.9(64) got stored as 9.6(x86). Thank you.

Comment: I guess only two functions are present in 9.2 for json type : array_to_json and row_to_json.